# How to join the arbitrary numbers of arguments in the function in python?

Tags: python, string

```
a = ['a','b','c']

def my_func(*args):
    ans = ......
    return ans

r = my_func(*a)
```

I want to get back r = "[a][b][c]"

I have tried below

```
def my_func(*args):
    t = ''
    for i in args:
        t = t + '[' + i + ']'
    return t
```

Comment: Which programming language du you use?

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about it in python.

Answer (score 1):

The input is a sequence, so you should be able to do anything that a sequence supports, such as iterating, and get by index.

```
def my_func(*a):
    return "".join([f"[{i}]" for i in a])

my_func(*['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> '[a][b][c]'
```

`"".join(items)` turns a list/tuple of items into a string.
We can use a list comprehension to turn the input list, into a list of each item surrounded by `[` and `]`: `[f"[{i}]" for i in a]`.
Combining the 2, we get a function that surrounds each item by square brackets, then turns it into a single string.

Comment: I want to get back   >>> '[a][b][c]......[n]' not 'abc....n'

Comment: I've updated my answer and added an short explanation.

Comment: You should add that f-strings only work in Python 3.6+.

Comment: @b9s, I got the SyntaxError with ur solution.

Comment: Try `return "".join(["[%s]" % i for i in a])`.